# Enter commands in the command prompt after it's been opened in Java?

Tags: java, runtime, cmd

I would like to know how to enter commands into the cmd.exe (command prompt window) , after its been opened?

I have the code below to open cmd.exe:

```
Runtime rt= Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process process= rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd c:\\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2");
```

But after it's been opened, I'd like to enter "ant compile" or any line, how do I do that??

Comment: Quick solution, you should be able to `"cmd.exe /c cd c:\\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2 && ant compile"`

Comment: This did not work: it simply cd to ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2 Is there a more methodical way of entering multiple lines of codes in cmd.exe right after one another??

Comment: Try "cmd.exe /c cd c:\\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2 & ant compile"

Comment: This didnt work pushy, it still just cd to Execu... and didnt run ant compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to put the commands in a script and execute the script.

You will need to consume the output of the child process (stdout and stderr) on separate threads, or your process will block.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to open the command line to compile a program with a running program, check this out [how to compile & run java program in another java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program)

Comment: Hey @JCarlos, thanks for the response, but my goal is to run cmd commands from java, that execute other non-java tests/programs. Is there a methodical way of entering multiple lines of commands in cmd.exe with java language?

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to you question. But you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to set your process current directory (so you don't need to call "cd ..." anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass a List to the `ProcessBuilder`

```
  final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String cmd = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/";
    l.add("C:\\WINNT\\system32\\cmd.exe ");
    l.add("cd " + cmd);
    l.add("dir");
    l.add("java.exe -version");
```

Comment: huh? the list that ProcessBuilder accepts in constructor is a list with a single program command and arguments to pass to it. You can't pass a numerous program calls to it.