# How to run a java program through a different java program?

Tags: java, process

I want my java program to execute a different java program. I used following method.

(The program I want to run is Example.java)

```
class RunJava
{
public static void main(String a[])throws Exception
{
Runtime.getRunTime().exec("c:\\"+path+"\\javac Example.java");
Runtime.getRunTime().exec("c:\\"+path+"\\java Example");
}
```

But it is not working.
Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: `javac` should be the first.. before that path (and `java` too).

Comment: its not the classpath. It is path of where javac is located in the system

Comment: If the 2nd app. is on the run-time class-path of the first, it is both simpler and cleaner to just create an instance of it, or directly call the `main(String[])`..  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

please refer [how to compile & run java program in another java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program). Same solution available !!

Comment: It works fine, but I'm unable to understand how to give input to the 2nd program. And I am unable to post comment on the link you suggested. So could you answer this too?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an executable jar for the Example.java and place it in the path then execute it with:

```
Runtime.getRunTime().exec("c:/"+path+"/java -jar Example.jar");
```

Comment: That is a typically fragile implementation of `exec` that is bound to break..  See my earlier comment and link.