# how to compile & run java program in another java program-netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried running the accepted answer in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program) using netbeans. The class file created but it is not executing.
Here is  my code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Laj {

  private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
  }

  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      runProcess("javac /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3/Main.java");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      runProcess("java /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3/Main");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Main.java is just a print statement,

```
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Done");
 }
 }
```

and i am getting error

```
javac /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3/Main.java exitValue() 0

java /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3/Main stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class 
.home.shibin.NetBeansProjects.JavaApplication3.src.javaapplication3.Main

java /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3/Main exitValue() 1
```

Comment: Also paste your Main.java

Comment: have you tested those command lines before using them in your code? The problem is there: the executer is looking for the package home.shibin.NetBeansProjects.JavaApplication3.src.javaapplication3 (classpath issue)

Comment: This code works perfectly fine while executing using terminal.
When using netBeans, Class file is created in the folder home.shibin.NetBeansProjects.JavaApplication3.src.javaapplication3
but not executing.

Answer (score 0):

The command for running java program is `java packageName.programName` or `java packageName/programName` The problem here is that you are running the code with `java pathOfProgram/programname`. To resolve this you have to supply classpath using `-cp` argument followed by the programPath like shown below:

```
java -cp pathOfProgram packageName.programName
```

Comment: to add to above comment, your command should be [[ java -cp /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3 Main ]] I see no package statement, so it is in default package.  Also, just check out this link - http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html It maybe a bit advanced in case you are a beginner, but you will find some good practices there.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
runProcess("java -cp /home/shibin/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication3/src/javaapplication3 Main");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your java command should have classpath argument. Prefer to use cmd array. Java process api is not xommand line.