# Running Java Program in another Program gives error

Tags: java

I want to execute another Java program in my program. I have taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program). For testing I have pasted same code as accepted answer shows.I have passed a simple HelloWorld program. Program compiles perfectly but gives Main class not found error.

Here is my code:
Server.java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        runProcess("javac D:\\HelloWorld.java");
        runProcess("java D:\\HelloWorld");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
}

private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
}
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
`public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}`
```

Output:
`exitValue() 0 for javac
stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class D:\HelloWorld
exitValue() 1 for java`

Compiling and running same program on CMD or IDE gives perfect output.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Is `HelloWorld` in a package?
Also, have you tried running the "java D:\\HelloWorld" command yourself?

Comment: do you have the `.class` file in the alleged path? `d:\HelloWorld`

Comment: Your class (run with the `java ___` command) is not going to be called `D:\HelloWorld`. It will be called `HelloWorld` or `packagename/HelloWorld`.

Comment: and not just that, D:\ won't be on the classpath unless it's explicitly added so it won't ever find the class if it's there.

Comment: As mentioned above, you probably want to cd to the correct folder where the HelloWorld.class file was created before trying to run it. Or maybe you could simply use `runProcess("d: && java HelloWorld");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start `main` from HelloWorld class? I think, in that case you should run program something like this:

```
java -cp 'D:\' HelloWorld
```

So, you need to specify ClassPath - 'D:\' and entry class name from classpath - HelloWorld.

Answer (score -1):

Why try to do things the hard way? Use the inline compiler API and then simply execute the main() method on your new class after loading the class itself into your root classloader.

Comment: May be ton of reasons. From unwillingness to load classes to the same classloader (or making some tricky stuff with classloaders because, for example, external code uses dependencies with another versions) to unstable external program, that you don't want to execute inside your main process to don't get OOM for example. Very specific question with valid field, no need to rephrase it.